# How to code html on pc and see the results on a mobile phone (android)?

Tags: windows, android, html

I want to code a web page for mobile devices. Is there any program which transfers the web page result into my phone directly? I've tried Chrome's and Firefox's mobile view on pc but it's not realistic. I want to test it in an android phone without transferring the file every time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 easy ways to do this:

1: Upload the website to your web host and just view it direct, Packages like Dreamweaver can do this on the fly.

eg: http://www.foo.com/test/
or: http://test.foo.com/

2: Connect your phone to your internal network (it probably already is) and have your PC "serve" it via IIS (native) or another webhost package.

eg: http://192.168.0.12/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the mobile view on your browser, the easiest you could do to see the change in real time from your phone would be to host the web page on your computer and access it from the phone with the local ip adress of your computer(if both are on the same network).

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html